# Настройка формы

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Мне нужно отправить форму с телефоном, НО, мне приходило пустое сообщение, а когда прописывал button с верхней формой, то все приходило. Как видите, я пытался разделить две формы, чтобы структура кнопки и формы не пропала на сайте, но тогда не приходит сообщение с номером телефона. Можно как объединить их, оставив такую структуру, как на картинке? PHP код

```
<?php
$message = 'Телефон: '.$_POST['phone']; 

mail('почта', 'Хайф', $message, "From: почта");
?>
```

```html
<div class="col-md-5  clearfix">
    <div class="low_tel">
        <form action="send.php" method="post">  
            <input id="low_tel" name="tel" type="text" placeholder="Телефон">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
                
<div class="col-md-3  clearfix">
    <div class="blue_btn" id="form">
        <form action="send.php" method="POST">
            <button id="zakaz_5min" class="ya-link" data-goal="form5min" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url(../img/blue_btn.png) no-repeat scroll left center; border: none; font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'officinaserifcregular'; ">Отправить заявку</button>
        </form>
    </div>  
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#form").submit(function (e) { // Устанавливаем событие отправки для формы с id=form
    e.preventDefault();
    var form_data = $(this).serialize(); // Собираем все данные из формы
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", // Метод отправки
        url: "send.php", // Путь до php файла отправителя
        data: form_data,
        success: function () {
            // Код в этом блоке выполняется при успешной отправке сообщения
            alert("Ваше сообщение отправлено!");
        }
    });
 });
</script>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объедините формы в одну

Приблизительно так

```
<form action="send.php" method="post">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5  clearfix">
      <div class="low_tel">
        <input id="low_tel" name="tel" type="text" placeholder="Телефон">
      </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="col-md-3  clearfix">
      <div class="blue_btn" id="form">
        <button id="zakaz_5min" class="ya-link" data-goal="form5min" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url(../img/blue_btn.png) no-repeat scroll left center; border: none; font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'officinaserifcregular'; ">Отправить заявку</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```